# mongoose update object-type schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update my database but stacked on how to achieve this. 
I'm able to find the right document but i don't know how to update this due to the 'or' condition. Any suggestion?

#### My User schema

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    local:{
        localId: {type:Number},
        username:{type:String},
        password: {type:String},
        email:{type:String}     
    },
    facebook:{
        facebookId: {type:Number},
        email:{type:String},
        username:{type:String},
        password: {type:String}       
    },
    twitter:{
        twitterId: {type:Number},
        username:{type:String},
        password: {type:String},  
        email:{type:String}       

    }
});
```

#### app.js

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({$or: [
              {'local.username': username }, // 'or' condition works perfect
           { 'facebook.username': username },
            { 'twitter.username': username },
  ]},{
    email:req.body.email // doesn't work...here i don't know what to do... 
  },function(err, user) {
            if(err){console.log(err);} 
              if(!user){
                console.log('cannot find user');
              }
              if(user){              
                console.log(user);
                   return res.send(JSON.stringify(user));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to '$set' the email field.

```
   User.findOneAndUpdate({$or: [
          {'local.username': username }, // 'or' condition works perfect
       { 'facebook.username': username },
        { 'twitter.username': username },
]},{
  $set:{email:req.body.email} // doesn't work...here i don't know what to do... 
},function(err, user) {
        if(err){console.log(err);} 
          if(!user){
            console.log('cannot find user');
          }
          if(user){              
            console.log(user);
               return res.send(JSON.stringify(user));

        }
    });
```